# Is there any function in Databricks PySpark that works similar to Unbox class in AWS Glue Dynamic frame?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, aws-glue

I am trying to convert json data in a column of df, which is showing as string but actually is of struct type. I know there is Unbox class in AWS Glue dynamic frame setup that can easily convert this string into struct (for ref https://aprakash.wordpress.com/2020/02/26/aws-glue-querying-nested-json-with-relationalize-transform/
) I am looking of there is any class/function/way to do same in databricks pyspark dataframe?

[image]
[image]

These images are for reference to show how they are working in AWS Glue setup.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60296276/4326922